# Does C4 damage stack?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Although not really an issue in Multiplayer, I've found in survival mode that using multiple C4 blocks at once doesn't seem to do as much damage as individual C4 attacks.

For example - a Juggernaut. 5-6 C4 blocks will kill him, but only one at a time. I throw 8 or 9 C4 blocks on the ground in one area and blow them at once, the juggernaut seems to shrug them off.

Is this just in my head, or is there a genuine lack of 'damage stack' for this particular method?

Comment: Ooof, both seem good answers and both have one vote. Will leave it till the end of the week before I place my tick, but thanks to you both for answering.

Comment: Atcually. One of the most unusual way to kill a juggernaut is by dropping a Care Package on top of him. It works. But you need a little bit practice about Precision Timing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually 5-6 (I use 10 everytime to be sure) blocks of C4 will kill a Jugg, and at the same time, not individually. They key is placement, and how you put the C4 down. Dont put them spread out in a small area, place them all in THE EXACT SAME SPOT, dont move your cursor and just repeatedly press the PLACE C4 Button appropriate for your platform. I know for a fact this works because I do it almost every day.

Key places where this works is in the CENTER of the floor in a small hallway, or right inside of a doorjamb you plan on luring them through, the wall of a small hallway, anywhere you can predictably get them to move within say 2 feet of the C4 packs works fine.

This tells me, and therefore you, :) that C4 DOES stack.

NOTE: WHILE YOU ARE PLACING THE C4 it is 'live'. So, if an enemy is shooting at you, and one of their stray bullets hits your C4 AS IT IS LEAVING YOUR HAND TO BE PLACED, the pack will blow and kill you. (friendly fire applies as well, as does any explosions friendly or otherwise that interfere AS YOUR PLACING THE C4)

THAT SAID: *once the C4 is placed* it becomes stable, and no enemy fire, explosions, ect, will blow it. So you can safely booby trap a room with C4 all over the freaking place, and get into a massive firefight in that room, relativly safely. Once its placed and still, the only thing that will blow it is your clacker (or double tapping reload, which is a 'hotkey' for the clacker.)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, the issue with big stacks of C4 is more their limited blast radius, (or high damage falloff, it's hard to say which) and not that the damage doesn't stack.

I find that it's easier to carefully lure an enemy into the perfect zone for a single block of C4, but it's much harder to lay a large pile of C4 and get them all perfectly aligned so that an enemy passing close to one is within the optimal distance to take maximum damage from all of them.

I've found the most effective way to force the Juggernaut to do something predictable is the lowly flash grenade.  Hitting them with one causes them to stagger for several seconds, which can give you time to make a small pile of C4 that more optimally delivers damage.

However, since they're stunned, (and in the case of the riot shield Juggernaut, causes him to lower his defenses) it's also relatively easy to get major headshot damage, which is notably cheaper than a stack of C4.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the previous answers, and I realize they mainly talk about specific scenarios in Survival Mode.

In solo, the first three juggernaut rounds consist of just juggernauts and no foot soldiers. When that happens, run to the spot the helicopter drops off the juggernaut, which will be the set place closest to you. When a smoke grenade drops, throw C4 about three feet towards you from the smoke explosion, if they stack it does not matter. The reason you are throwing towards you is to make sure the juggernaut is moving before you blow them up.

The most likely problem you are having is that you are blowing up the C4 too early. Before the juggernaut starts moving, he is invincible; as is the helicpter, so predator missiles hitting the copter wont do anything.

Lastly, the juggernaut can be killed by ONLY 4 C4'S! I find this ironic because of the 4 in C4. I have killed the juggernaut also with 6 closely placed claymores.

I hoped this helped you to survive longer in Survival Mode, and keep blowing up those explosives!!!